# Why isn't this button showing when the state is false?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state

I have created a component to function as a "Like/Unlike" button. When the state is true, the "Unlike" button successfully displays, but when I click "Unlike", and it DOES unlike successfully, the state should be set to false as (liked: false). However, I don't see the button. 
One thing I noticed is, when I click "Unlike", the "Unlike" button disappears and the "Like" button does appear, for a millisecond, and then it vanishes in thin air. I cannot figure it out why.

Here are all the codes for my like button component:

```
import React from "react";
import { API, graphqlOperation } from "aws-amplify";
import { Button } from "element-react";
import { createLike, deleteLike } from "../graphql/mutations";
import { UserContext } from "../App";

class Like extends React.Component {
  state = {
    liked: "",
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setLiked();
  }

  setLiked() {
    console.log(this.props);
    const { user } = this.props;
    const { post } = this.props;
    if (post.likes.items.find((items) => items.liker === user.username)) {
      this.setState({ liked: true });
      console.log("liked: true");
    } else {
      this.setState({ liked: false });
      console.log("liked: false");
    }
  }

  handleLike = async (user) => {
    try {
      const input = {
        liker: user.username,
        likePostId: this.props.postId,
      };
      await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(createLike, { input }));
      this.setState({
        liked: true,
      });
      console.log("Liked!");
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("Failed to like", err);
    }
  };

  handleUnlike = async (likeId) => {
    try {
      const input = {
        id: likeId,
      };
      await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(deleteLike, { input }));
      this.setState({
        liked: false,
      });
      console.log("Unliked!");
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("Failed to unlike", err);
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { like } = this.props;
    const { liked } = this.state;
    return (
      <UserContext.Consumer>
        {({ user }) => (
          <React.Fragment>
            {liked ? (
              <Button type="primary" onClick={() => this.handleUnlike(like.id)}>
                Unlike
              </Button>
            ) : (
              <Button
                type="primary"
                onClick={() => this.handleLike(user, like.id)}
              >
                Like
              </Button>
            )}
          </React.Fragment>
        )}
      </UserContext.Consumer>
    );
  }
}

export default Like;
```

The code of the parent component:

```
import React from "react";
import { API, graphqlOperation } from "aws-amplify";
import {
  onCreateComment,
  onCreateLike,
  onDeleteLike,
} from "../graphql/subscriptions";
import { getPost } from "../graphql/queries";
import Comment from "../components/Comment";
import Like from "../components/Like";
import LikeButton from "../components/LikeButton";
import { Loading, Tabs, Icon } from "element-react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { S3Image } from "aws-amplify-react";
import NewComment from "../components/NewComment";

class PostDetailPage extends React.Component {
  state = {
    post: null,
    isLoading: true,
    isAuthor: false,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.handleGetPost();
    this.createCommentListener = API.graphql(
      graphqlOperation(onCreateComment)
    ).subscribe({
      next: (commentData) => {
        const createdComment = commentData.value.data.onCreateComment;
        const prevComments = this.state.post.comments.items.filter(
          (item) => item.id !== createdComment.id
        );
        const updatedComments = [createdComment, ...prevComments];
        const post = { ...this.state.post };
        post.comments.items = updatedComments;
        this.setState({ post });
      },
    });
    this.createLikeListener = API.graphql(
      graphqlOperation(onCreateLike)
    ).subscribe({
      next: (likeData) => {
        const createdLike = likeData.value.data.onCreateLike;
        const prevLikes = this.state.post.likes.items.filter(
          (item) => item.id !== createdLike.id
        );
        const updatedLikes = [createdLike, ...prevLikes];
        const post = { ...this.state.post };
        post.likes.items = updatedLikes;
        this.setState({ post });
      },
    });
    this.deleteLikeListener = API.graphql(
      graphqlOperation(onDeleteLike)
    ).subscribe({
      next: (likeData) => {
        const deletedLike = likeData.value.data.onDeleteLike;
        const updatedLikes = this.state.post.likes.items.filter(
          (item) => item.id !== deletedLike.id
        );
        const post = { ...this.state.post };
        post.likes.items = updatedLikes;
        this.setState({ post });
      },
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.createCommentListener.unsubscribe();
  }

  handleGetPost = async () => {
    const input = {
      id: this.props.postId,
    };
    const result = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(getPost, input));
    console.log({ result });
    this.setState({ post: result.data.getPost, isLoading: false }, () => {});
  };

  checkPostAuthor = () => {
    const { user } = this.props;
    const { post } = this.state;
    if (user) {
      this.setState({ isAuthor: user.username === post.author });
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { post, isLoading } = this.state;
    return isLoading ? (
      <Loading fullscreen={true} />
    ) : (
      <React.Fragment>
        {/*Back Button */}
        <Link className="link" to="/">
          Back to Home Page
        </Link>
        {/*Post MetaData*/}
        <span className="items-center pt-2">
          <h2 className="mb-mr">{post.title}</h2>
        </span>
        <span className="items-center pt-2">{post.content}</span>
        <S3Image imgKey={post.file.key} />
        <div className="items-center pt-2">
          <span style={{ color: "var(--lightSquidInk)", paddingBottom: "1em" }}>
            <Icon name="date" className="icon" />
            {post.createdAt}
          </span>
        </div>

        <div className="items-center pt-2">
          {post.likes.items.map((like) => (
            <Like
              user={this.props.user}
              like={like}
              post={post}
              postId={this.props.postId}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
        <div className="items-center pt-2">
          {post.likes.items.length}people liked this.
        </div>
        <div>
          Add Comment
          <NewComment postId={this.props.postId} />
        </div>
        {/* Comments */}
        Comments: ({post.comments.items.length})
        <div className="comment-list">
          {post.comments.items.map((comment) => (
            <Comment comment={comment} />
          ))}
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default PostDetailPage;
```

I think I know why it doesn't show up. It's because at first when the user hasn't liked it, there is no "like" object, so there is nothing to be shown, as it is only shown when there is a "like" mapped to it. I don't know how to fix it though.

Comment: Do you have any console errors? Perhaps there's a render error and React is blowing up and unmounting entirely.

Comment: Also, is this in a form? You're not preventing default on the buttons, so maybe the form is submitting, causing your page to load a new document.

Comment: @Jacob No There aren't any console error. It did give me the console.log("Unliked!"), so I suppose the state should be set to "false" correctly. And this is not a form. It is just a button. All the codes of this component are shown here.

Comment: This thing isn't mounted inside of a form element in your HTML document?

Comment: @Jacob No, it isn't.

Comment: @ProudHKer How many params does your `handleLike` function have?

Comment: It's not a React state thing. Stripping out all the non-vanilla stuff, the button toggles fine: https://codepen.io/srebalaji/pen/MVbWdB. Something outside the context of the code you posted is doing this.

Comment: @O.o Only one. "user.id" is a mistake I forgot to delete. It doesn't change the fact that the "Like" button is not showing though.

Comment: @ProudHKer It's easy to have a one button and change the button name based on the state value. it is easy to handle and prevent not-rendering issues imo.

Comment: @O.o It's not only changing the name, but the functions underlying are different. One has to like and one has to unlike.